# Geolocation doesn't work with cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, geolocation, intel-xdk

I'm currently working on a mobile application with Intel XDK (In background it's Cordova finally, that's why I put Cordova in title.)

With an Ajax request, I get some adresses and with these adresses I want to calculate the distance between them and the current position of user.

So, I get adresses, I convert them and I make the difference.

But actually, nothing is working !

```
function codeAddress(id, addresse) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addresse}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            setTimeout(function(){}, 100);
        }

        console.log(id);
        console.log(addresse);

        //document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",function(){
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    addressEvent = results[0].geometry.location;
                    var pos = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };
                    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng)
                    var resultat = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(addressEvent, position);
                    console.log(resultat);
                    console.log(addressEvent);
                    console.log(pos);
                    console.log(position);
                    var convert = Math.floor(resultat);
                    var finalConvert = convert + " m";
                    var distance = document.createElement('span');
                    distance.innerHTML = finalConvert;
                    distance.className = "geo";
                    document.getElementsByClassName('meta-info-geo')[id].appendChild(distance);
                }, function() {
                    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow);
                });
            }
        }
        //},false);
    });
}
```

In the console.log(id), console.log(addresse), I HAVE results !

Actually i'm getting 4 IDs and 4 adresses.

I checked on all the topics I could find on StackOverFlow, and I had normally to add the line in // with the addEventListener but it changes nothing.

Is there someone who knows how to change that ?

ps : Of course, cordova geoloc is in the build and permissions are granted !

EDIT : I'm targeting Android 4.0 min and iOS 5.1.1. I'm using SDK.

EDIT 2 : [image]

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on Cordova. Is this your first hybrid App? What is your target platform and their target versions? Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: I just did. But as I answered on the other post, my code is working, just the document.addEventListener which is not working :)

Comment: Hmmm.... There is a large possibility you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how Cordova/Phonegap works. This happens easily because in recent years Cordova/Phonegap are using HTML5 API - when possible. So it is possible you have an HTML5 App, but not a Cordova/Phonegap app. Is your code posted somewhere public so I can look at it? FWIW: your `document.addEventListener` issue may be because of this misunderstanding.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 On my project in Intel XDK, project type is : HTML5 + Cordova started from : Import. 
So I guess it's okay ? 
But I don't have anywhere cordova.js or anything else (like intelxdk.js)

Comment: Where is your code, so I can see it?

Comment: Which code ? I just upload an image of the plugin I have on the project, I think it's what you want

Comment: Okay. You are using marking from `intelxdk`. This tells me every time you use `intelxdk` - it will not work with the regular Cordova things. The least is I do not understand it. I think you should your question at the [Intelxdk forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk)

Comment: Yes i'm gonna do it, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Geolocation frequently does not work the way people expect it to work, for a variety of reasons that have been expressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34845605/2914328) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33612857/2914328).

You can experiment with geo by using the "Hello, Cordova" sample app that is in the XDK and also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/gomobile/sample-hello-cordova). Try using it on a variety of devices to see how things work. Push the "fine" button to initiate a single geo call for a "fine" location and push the "coarse" button to initiate a single geo call for a "coarse" location. Push the "watch" button to initiate a request for a series of geo data points (set to coarse or fine by pushing one of the single buttons first).

The behavior you get in the Emulate tab will be *dramatically* different than what you get on a real device. The type of device (Android, iOS, etc.) and the version of that device will influence your results; the manufacturer of the device and your location (inside or outside) will influence your results. Do not assume that making a call to the geo APIs will always give you immediate and reliable data, geolocation hardware does not work that way... In fact, you cannot assume that you can even get a valid result! See the two links I pointed to earlier in the post for some reasons why.

Comment: Thank's for the tips ! :)

Actually I just change few lines and it's working fine. 
The only problem I got is the double prompt for geoloc on iOS. 
I need to use this line : (//document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",function(){)
But I don't understand why he doesn't work =/

Comment: You need to include the geo plugin to eliminate the double prompt. I don't understand why, but that fixes that problem for me. But that means you need to wait for the deviceready event (aka Cordova Ready) before you access any geo functions. Do not use that intel.xdk.device.ready event, it has been deprecated, use the standard "deviceready" that is provided by Cordova.

Comment: I just edit my first post, as you can see it's already include in the project.
And I used intel.xdk.device because when I created my project, I never find cordova.js so I cannot use deviceready ...

Comment: `cordova.js` is a "phantom file" -- it does not exist in your project, it is added during the build and debug phases because it needs to be customized to match your project. See the comments in the `index.html` file in the "Hello, Cordova" sample I pointed you too for more details.

Comment: So I just need to add Cordova.js in intex.html or in all the files where i'm using deviceready ?

Comment: In general, it's best to stick to a single-page app when constructing Cordova apps. Otherwise, you have to reload the cordova.js with each new html page, and you lose the JavaScript context from the previous page (it also tends to slow down your app, the page switching and re-init of Cordova). See this Cordova doc page > https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/index.html

Comment: Alright, but my index.html is in my root directory, and all the others in the html directory, will it work ? or should I move all the file in the same location as index.html ? 
thank's for the link, i'm reading it right now

Comment: A `single-page app` means you have only one html file (e.g., `index.html`) and you create "pages" in your app by hiding and showing <div> elements located within that single page. Some frameworks use multiple html pages by inserting the contents of those other html pages into the main page, which accomplishes the same result (there is really only one html page). In those cases the other html pages are really just html fragments, they are not fully composed html pages that can be loaded as independent units.

Comment: Wow okay, I got it but I never did it and don't know how actually.

Comment: See this Cordova doc for some reasoning behind why you should use the `single-page app` approach to building your Cordova/PhoneGap apps > https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/ <